# What JARs are needed for Spring 4.2.6 version to create a CRUD project using Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I'm creating Spring MVC CRUD Operations for a sample project. But I'm
    confused what JARs should I need to build. when I look at some tutorials they 
    were using Spring 3.0.1 version. When I add the same JARs the project is not 
    able to run. I have created the same copy of the tutorial for code. But I'm 
    unable to run. Please help me with this task.

Comment: [check this out](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core)

Comment: and [this](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=spring+4.2.6)

Comment: @sysquare, my questions what JARS are needed to build CRUD operations for basic task. I have 4.2.6 JARS but I'm not getting the project run by using the JARs which are shown in tutorials(where they used 3.0.2 version)

Comment: what jars are u using now and what issue are u facing ? Better use Gradle/Maven for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use maven plugin to create the project. Mars has inbuilt maven plugin. 
Go through this link.

[Link](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/creating-a-spring-mvc-project-using-maven-and-eclipse-in-one-minute)

Comment: "The requested page cannot be found.